# How to use bash process substitution for a sftp private key file?

Tags: bash, sftp, process-substitution, password-store

With my team, we need to share a few private keys and we store them in a [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) repository.

So instead of extracting the key and storing it in cleartext on the filesystem, I am looking for a way to only keep the decrypted version shortly in memory:

```
$ sftp -i <(pass foo) user@host
Warning: Identity file /dev/fd/63 not accessible: No such file or directory.
```

Any idea why sftp is unable to read the temporary file descriptor? How to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Any idea why `sftp` is unable to read the temporary file descriptor?

Few facts:

- the `<(pass foo)` process substitution will cause `bash` to create a pipe, run the `pass foo` command asynchronously with its output connected to the writing end of the pipe and replace the `<(...)` with a path of the form `/dev/fd/63`, where `63` is the file descriptor referring to the reading end of the pipe.
- the `/dev/fd/63` is a special path which allows a process to `stat()` and re-open the file referred by one of its file descriptors.
- the shell forks + execs `sftp`, then `sftp` itself forks and execs `ssh`, causing the `63` file descriptor to be passed down via inheritance.
- `ssh` will [close all its file descriptors](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/37638c752041d591371900df820f070037878a2d/ssh.c#L617) except 0, 1, 2 using the `closefrom()` function. That will also close fd `63`.

Since `63` is no longer an open file descriptor in the `ssh` process, a `stat()` on `/dev/fd/63` will fail with the error from the OP.

> How to fix it?

Temporarily store the key in a filesystem in memory. In my Debian `systemd` provides me tmpfs under [`/run/user/<myUID>`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/162900/108618). The mountpoint is inaccessible to anyone but me (and root, of course).

Note a rogue process running under your user (or root) can read the file. But such process could also read from `sshd`'s file descriptor `63` in your original approach.

Alternatively, when there is no safe tmpfs available:

1. Create a temporary fifo. Note `mktemp` cannot do this directly. The safe way is to create a temporary private *directory* and then `mkfifo` in it.
2. Make sure the permissions of the fifo itself are narrow, otherwise `ssh` will complain.
3. Run

   ```
   sftp -i "/temp_dir/the_fifo" user@host
   ```
4. In parallel run `pass foo > "/temp_dir/the_fifo"`. A quirk: you need to do this *twice*; at least in my Debian `ssh` reads the key twice. The following command seems to work in my tests: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa > "/temp_dir/the_fifo" && cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa > "/temp_dir/the_fifo"`. Probably a similar duplicated command will work for you:

   ```
   pass foo > "/temp_dir/the_fifo" && pass foo > "/temp_dir/the_fifo"
   ```

   You can run it in the background just before `sftp` (unless `pass` is interactive, I'm not familiar with the tool at all).
5. At the end remove the fifo and the directory.

Still, a rogue process running under your user (or root) can read from the fifo before `ssh` does.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Especially the "sftp itself forks and execs ssh" part, I should have thought about that! Regarding the fix, especially wanted to avoid storing it somewhere it could be stolen by someone who owns the machine. But it would still be better than storing a copy on the filesystem.