# How to resize the `/run` directory?

Tags: linux

A  Nix  custom image  build  kept  failing with  the
message `No space left  on device` on Ubuntu 18.04.4
LTS,  and was  able to  track it  down using  `watch -n  -1  "df  -h"`   while  running  the  build.  The
culprit  ended up  being a  `/run` mountpoint  (more
specifically, `/run/user/1000`) and, indirectly, the
swap space.

This is how it looked like before:

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
tmpfs                        785M   28K  785M   1% /run/user/1000
...
```

Comment: If you're ever getting `No space left on device` on `/run`, you have a _much_ more fundamental problem that needs resolution.

Answer (score 8):

### 1. Resize `/run` mountpoints

According to the
[`tmpfs` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt)
, "*`tmpfs` has three mount options for sizing"* where
**size** is

> The  limit   of  allocated  bytes  for   this  tmpfs
> instance. The  default is half of  your physical RAM
> without swap.  If you oversize your  tmpfs instances
> the machine will deadlock since the OOM handler will
> not be able to free that memory.

That  is to  say, it  can be  set to  an arbitrarily
large size, but  **make sure that there  is enough RAM
or  swap  space  (or combination thereof), so adjust
the latter if needed (see 4. below).

In my case,  I set it to 15 GB  for starters, and it
was enough.

```bsh
sudo mount -o remount,size=15G,noatime /run/user/1000
```

### 2. Adjust swap space

#### 2.1 Temporarily

Used [this Askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space/534090#534090) in the following way:

Check current swap:

```
$ free -th
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        4.6G        253M        985M        2.8G        1.8G
Swap:          975M          0B        975M
Total:         8.6G        4.6G        1.2G

$ sudo swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-2                               partition       999420  3840    -2
```

Setting up the swap file, and turning it on:

```
$ sudo touch /temp_swap_15G.img
$ sudo fallocate -l 15G /temp_swap_15G.img
$ sudo mkswap /temp_swap_15G.img

# `-p` is the priority; the default is -2 and anything
# higher will be used first
$ sudo swapon -p 27 /temp_swap_15G.img
```

Checking the results:

```
$ sudo swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-2                               partition       999420  4352    -2
/temp_swap_15G.img                      file            15728636        0       27
```

#### 2.2 Permanently

StackExchange answers (snapshots available on archive.org):

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/226520/how-can-i-modify-the-size-of-swap-with-lvm-partitions

This is a troubleshooting one for the LVM one:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/733407/insufficient-free-space-x-extents-needed-but-only-y-available

---

**Note**: On NixOS, instead of the steps above, the process would have been simply

1. to   edit   the   `services.logind.extraConfig`
   attribute in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`:

```
  services.logind.extraConfig = ''
    RuntimeDirectorySize=12G
    HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
  '';
```

2. Rebuild configuration (e.g., with `sudo nixos-rebuild switch`).

More info:

- [NixOS option: services.logind.extraConfig](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#services.logind.extraconfig)
- https://releases.nixos.org/nix-dev/2015-July/017657.html

---

#### What is `/run`?

[This](https://lwn.net/Articles/436012/)
is the authoriative answer, but
[this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-significance-of-the-run-directory-in-Linux)
sums it up:

> `/run` is the "early bird" equivalent to `/var/run`,
> in  that it's  meant for  system daemons  that start
> very  early  on  (e.g.   `systemd`  and  `udev`)  to
> store  temporary runtime  files like  PID files  and
> communication  socket  endpoints,  while  `/var/run`
> would be used by  late-starting daemons (e.g. `sshd`
> and Apache).
>
> Traditional  `/var/run` was  an actual  directory on
> disk, which meant the  underlying filesystem may not
> have  been  mounted at  the  point  `systemd` et  al
> needed  to  write stuff  into  it.  Making `/run`  a
> tmpfs (i.e. RAM-based) filesystem neatly solved this
> problem and  eliminated the need  to clean it  up on
> the next boot.
>
> Of  course, having  two runtime  scratch directories
> struck many as  being a bit much, so  in many modern
> Linux  distros,  `/var/run`  is just  a  symlink  to
> `/run`.

### What is  `tmpfs`?

[kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt):

> Everything in  tmpfs is temporary in  the sense that
> no files will be created  on your hard drive. If you
> unmount a tmpfs  instance, everything stored therein
> is lost.
>
> tmpfs  puts  everything  into  the  kernel  internal
> caches  and grows  and  shrinks  to accommodate  the
> files it contains and is able to swap unneeded pages
> out to swap space. It  has maximum size limits which
> can be  adjusted on  the fly  via `mount  -o remount ...`

Also, "*tmpfs lives completely in the page cache and
on swap*".

Comment: This WWW site already has the more specific https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/162900/5132 , note.